# window.onpopstate and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

Any ideas about how to store and restore scroll position throught `history.pushState`?

On `window.onpopstate` and `$('body a').click` events my engine renders page, and I want to store and restore scroll position after rendering. But I misunderstand how I can store scroll position in `history.state`. I tried to put current scroll before pushing new url, but when it's restored via `window.onpopstate` its value is incorrect.

Maybe some working expamles?

Thank you!